# Accessing the indices and operating on the elements of lists in Mathematica

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have a data file from which I import data to lists,

```
list1 = Import["path", "Table"]
```

it returns a list in the following form,

> list1 = {{9,2.5},{2,3.5},{3,4.5},....}

Now I have another `list2` which is of same length as `list1`.
When I try

```
list2-list1
```

I get

```
{{0,xx},{0,yy},{0,zz},...}
```

But, I would like to make a difference plot `(list2-list1)` vs whole numbers `(9, 2, 3)`.

How do I do this?

Comment: It is unclear to me what you are asking. Please provide a working example with complete sample data and the desired output for that data.

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simulate `list1` and `list2`:

```
list1 = Transpose @ {RandomInteger[{0, 9}, 10], RandomReal[1, 10]};
list2 = Transpose @ {First @ Transpose @ list1, RandomReal[1, 10]};
```

Create a list for plot:

```
list3 = Transpose @ {list1[[All, 1]], (list2 - list1)[[All, 2]]}

ListPlot[list3, Frame -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> {Black, PointSize[Medium]}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"integers", "difference"}]
```

[image]